# Instagram Tag Recent search always return null array

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I wanna find specific tags media and these infos.

And, followed instagram API Document.

But, specific tags media API always returnd null array.

I tried this step.

1. Get a AccessToken

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[C_ID]&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/instagram/callback&response_type=token&scope=basic+public_content+relationships

Redirect And return accestoken

http://localhost:3001/instagram/callback#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

2. Find specific Tag(ex. snow)

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Returned,

```
{
     "meta": 
     {
         "code": ​200
     },
     "data": 
           {
            "media_count": ​11664,
            "name": "snow"
      }

 }
```

3. And Find Specific tag media list

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Returned,

```
{

    "pagination": 

{

    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"

},
"meta": 

    {
        "code": ​200
    },
    "data": [ ]

}
```

Why return null array?

And what is max_tag_id, min_tag_id?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost definitely seeing no results because the hashtag you are searching for has not been used in your last 20 posts.

This is a short [article explaining how the new Instagram API works](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.psynexzi3).

TL;DR: If your app is in sandbox mode, it can only see see the past 20 posts by you or your Sandbox users.